# Change font size in "confirmation" email?

Tags: html, email, paypal

I'm not really sure how to explain what I am looking for, so I'll try my best.

I use paypal for processing purchases online. When someone makes a purchase, I receive an html email from Paypal showing me the customers order and info.

What I want to do is change the way this email looks when it comes to me. For example, the fonts are small and hard to read (for me) and I am wondering if I can stylize these emails somehow, to set the fonts larger?

I hope this makes sense. I kind of doubt it's possible, but figure its worth an ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... this isn't really a programming question.  Why you don't just change the font size in your email client?

Comment: Since the emails are formatted by Paypal, my email client settings don't seem to effect them.

I thought maybe it was a programming question because maybe I could find a way to dictate the settings of how the mail was formatted at the source. Like a font size html/css setting or something.

Comment: My best guess is to dig around your PayPal settings to see if there are any such configuration options, but I doubt it.  You may be able to tweak your email client.  No idea what mail client you use, but it looks like Greasemonkey can work in Thunderbird, so that may be an option.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/collections/tekeek/gmonkeyessentials/

Comment: Thanks! I have tried looking through the paypal settings and options, I can't seem to find anything. Was just hoping someone may know a trick for me. Oh well.